# 2バイトの10進数を全角文字に変換して出力する方法がわからない。

Tags: c, 文字コード

C言語でbase64のデコーダを作成しています。自分のやり方だと、例えばエンコードされた平仮名の「あ」をデコードするときに、2バイトのデータを一度10進数に変換しました。すると33440(0x82a0)の値が計算できてSJISの2バイトの文字コード表と照らし合わせると平仮名の[あ」を指しているのですが、2バイトのデータである(0x82a0)を文字に変換して出力する方法がわかりません。

環境
win7 64bit
vs 2013

Comment: Base64と言うのは、バイナリデータをテキスト表現に変換する方法の一つです。バイナリデータの元が文字列だったからといって、1文字単位に区切って変換することには意味がありません。あなたが本当にやりたいのは「Base64に(から?)変換」することでしょうか? それもとBase64とは異なる何かで1文字単位の変換をすることでしょうか?

Comment: よく理解せずに質問して申し訳ございません。

Comment: よく理解できないことがあるから質問につながるわけで、そのこと自体は別に構いません。ただ、本当にしたいことは何か、と言うのを明らかにしないまま細部にこだわってしまうとあなたが直面している問題をうまく解決することはできません。まずは、本当にやりたいことは何か、をうまく説明することを心がけてください。そうすれば、2バイトのデータを文字に変換することが必要かどうかも含めて的確な回答が得られるはずです。

Comment: 最初にBASE 64の文字コードを元にして、入力された文字列に対してエンコードするプログラムを作成しました。半角の文字に対しては、デコードできていると思うのですが、全角の文字ができません。エンコードされたデータを1バイト単位で取り出して文字に変換したことが原因だと思い全角の場合は2バイトのバイナリデータを文字に変換する必要があると思うのですが、それができないです。

Comment: 私がやりたいのはbase64で、入力された文字を一度エンコードして、そのあとデコードして元に戻すということをやりたいです。

Comment: まずはエンコードとデコードという用語をしっかり使い分けてください。Base64の場合だと、Base64の文字列→バイナリデータと言うのが「デコード」にあたります。バイナリデータ→Base64の文字列と言う変換が「エンコード」です。バイナリデータが実は何らかの(「あ」のような日本語文字を含む)文字列データを表しているかもしれませんが、そのことは切り離した方がいいですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみに、例えば10進数の整数(33440)を文字で出力するにはどうすればいいかという質問もおかしなことを言っているのでしょうか？

Comment: おかしなこととは思いませんが、Base64の処理としては全く意味がありません。

Comment: そのやり方を教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 2バイト文字とかにこだわらずにBase64に変換する場合の概念を回答にまとめています。回答の中でわかりにくいところや、そこは聞きたいこととはちょっと違うと言う点があれば、回答へのコメントをお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

Base64と言うのは3バイト単位のバイナリデータをASCII文字中の特定の64文字から4文字を使って表すための方法です。元の「バイナリデータ」が何らかの文字列を表していたとしても、文字ごとの区切りが処理の区切りになることはありません。

例えば、元の文字列として`"Aあ"`なんて2文字からなる文字列を考えてみます。これをSJISのバイナリデータで表すと、

```
41 82 A0
```

の3バイトになります。これをBase64に変換する場合には、`41 82 A0`の3バイトをまとめて変換する必要があります。`"A"`と`"あ"`は別の文字だからといって、文字単位で処理するとBase64にはなりません。

```
41 82 A0 ⇒ "QYKg"
```

こうやって、なんらかのバイナリデータが元としてある場合に、それから(`"QYKg"`のような)文字列表現を作ることが、「Base64エンコード」です。このバイナリデータがどうやって作られたのか、はBase64とは直接の関係はありません。

---

逆に入力としてBase64の文字列がある場合、それを4文字ごとに区切って処理します。

今仮にBase64の入力が`"QYKg"`だったとします。この場合、全体がちょうど4文字ですから、この4文字をまとめて、バイナリデータに変換しないといけません。

で、その結果が`41 82 A0`と言う3バイトのバイナリデータになります。

で、この`41 82 A0`と言う3バイトのバイナリデータを作ると言う処理が、Base64のデコードをした、と言うことになります。その3バイトが実はSJIS文字列を表しているとかなんとかは、Base64とは直接関係なく、バイナリデータをいかに文字列として解釈するのか、と言った部分になります。

(追記)
この「バイナリデータをいかに文字列として解釈するのか」まで必要なのであれば、C言語の文字列のルールに従って末尾にNULを付け加えてやるだけです。例えば`binBuf`なんて十分なサイズを持った`char`配列に`len`バイト(`int`型)の「バイナリデータ」が出来ているとしたら、

```
//...あなたのBase64デコード処理の後
binBuf[len] = '\0';
printf("result=%s\n", binBuf); //-> Aあ
```

と言ったコードを書いてやれば、一文字ずつ変換する必要なく元の文字列が表示されます。(もちろん出力先の端末の文字コードは元の文字列の文字コードと同じである必要があります。)

※Base64エンコードする前の元データに末尾のNUL文字を入れておけば、デコードした後NUL終端する必要がなくなるんですが、他言語で作ったBase64テキストと結果が違ってくるのであまりやりません。

---

いかがでしょうか?まだ何か違うと言う点があればおしらせください。

Comment: 特に目的があったわけではないのですが、このBase64がwikipediaで電子メールで使われていることを知りました。自分の解釈では、例えば、"A" "あ”という文字はメールが届く過程で"Qykg"に一度変換されるのかと思い、回答でいただいている「Base64エンコード」という処理はすることができました。そこで元の文字列に戻すために、Qykgからバイナリデータである41, 82, A0も作ることはできたのですが、"A" "あ"という文字列で読めるようにしたいです。

Comment: よくわからないのですが、`"A"`と`"あ"`のように区切る必要があるのでしょうか? C言語の文字列はNUL(0x00)終端された文字コードの並びですので、一文字ごとに区切らなくとも末尾をNUL終端してやれば、`"Aあ"`と言う文字列が得られます。